# Can I rely on empty parameter packs to be expanded properly?

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

The following code defines function `subst_first`, which substitutes the first elements of an array of ints by the contents of another array. It works under gcc and clang ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64a860ea9ccd6ed4)). For cases `//1`, `//2` and `//3` one of the generated [`index_sequence`'s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) is empty. Consequently one of the parameter packs at `//4` has zero elements. This makes me feel uneasy. Can I rely on this behavior to be standard conforming?

```
template<size_t n, size_t ... S1, size_t ... S2>
constexpr
std::array<int,3>
subst_first_impl( std::array<int,n> const &v1,
                  std::array<int,3> const &v2,
                  size_t min_n,
                  std::index_sequence<S1...>,
                  std::index_sequence<S2...> )
{    return std::array<int,3>{{ v1[S1]..., v2[min_n+S2]... }}; } // 4

template<size_t n>
constexpr
std::array<int,3>
subst_first( std::array<int,n> const &v1,
             std::array<int,3> const &v2 )
{   auto const min_n= std::min( size_t(3), n );
    return subst_first_impl( v1, v2, min_n,
                             std::make_index_sequence< min_n >(),
                             std::make_index_sequence< size_t(3) - min_n >() );
}

int main(){
    constexpr std::array<int,3>  a1{{1,2,3}};

    constexpr std::array<int,2>  b1{{4,5}};
    constexpr std::array<int,3>  b2{{6,7,8}};
    constexpr std::array<int,4>  b3{{9,10,11,12}};
    constexpr std::array<int,0>  b4{};

    constexpr auto b1a1= subst_first( b1, a1 );
    // ==> 4, 5, 3

    constexpr auto b2a1= subst_first( b2, a1 ); // 1
    // ==> 6, 7, 8

    constexpr auto b3a1= subst_first( b3, a1 ); // 2
    // ==> 9, 10, 11

    constexpr auto b4a1= subst_first( b4, a1 ); // 3
    // ==> 1, 2, 3
}
```

**Note:** I am not looking for a solution for substituting elements of arrays. I am interested in the behavior of `index_sequence`'s and parameter packs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `std::make_index_sequence<0>` is perfectly valid (§20.5.3 [intseq.make]):

> *[ Note: make_integer_-sequence<int, 0> denotes the type integer_sequence<int> —end note ]*

So in your case, you get a `std::index_sequence<size_t>`.

And per §14.5.3/7 [temp.variadic], the instantiation of a pack expansion of length 0 is perfectly valid:

> The instantiation of a pack expansion that is neither a `sizeof...` expression nor a fold-expression produces a list E1, E2, ..., EN, where N is the number of elements in the pack expansion parameters. [...]
>
> All of the E<sub>i</sub> become elements in the enclosing list. [...] When **N is zero**, the instantiation of the expansion **produces an empty list**. Such an instantiation does not alter the syntactic interpretation of the enclosing construct, even in cases where omitting the list entirely would otherwise be ill-formed or would result in an ambiguity in the grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely. Quoting the standard [temp.variadic]:

> 4. A pack expansion consists of a pattern and an ellipsis, the
>      instantiation of which produces **zero or more** instantiations of the
>      pattern in a list. The form of the pattern depends on the context in
>      which the expansion occurs.

So the standard accommodates the expansion of packs whose size is zero.